# using reg exp how can i replace file name alone?

Tags: jquery, regex

my src:

```
Video/webm/Task_2.4a_Host_treated.webm

Video/ogv/Task_2.4a_Host_treated.theora.ogv

Video/MP4/Task_2.4a_Host_treated.mp4
```

i need to replace the (Task_2.4a_Host_treated.theora or Task_2.4a_Host_treated ) areas alone? how can do this using reg.exp?

Answer (score 0):

[Working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Hat2k/)

This regular expression would match everything after the last forward slash, capturing the extension in its own group, so it can be put back in place when we do the replacement:

```
var regex = /\/[^/]*?(\.[^/.]*)?$/mg;
```

Now you can do the replacement with (where `$1` refers to the captured group, i.e. the file extension):

```
str = str.replace(regex, '/whatyouwanttohaveinstead$1');
```

Note that I used the `m` modifier to switch on multi-line mode. Due to this `$` matches the end of every line (in addition to the end of the string).

Some explanation of the parts of the regular expression:

```
\/         # matches a literal slash
[^/]*      # matches arbitrarily many non-slash characters
?          # makes the previous repetition ungreedy, so it does not consume the
           # file extension if there is one
(          # starts a capturing group, which can be accessed later with $1
\.         # matches a literal period
[^/.]*     # matches as many non-period/non-slash characters as possible
)          # closes the capturing group
?          # makes the file extension optional
$          # matches the end of the string, and due to the "m" modifier later
           # the end of every line
```

Since none of those characters can be a `/` and we anchor the match to the end of the string with `$`, this will only be everything after the last slash. Note that I have included `/` in the negative character class of the file extension as well. Otherwise you might get problems with directories containing periods and files without file extensions (in `test/directory.containing.dots/file` you would match everything after the **first** slash).

Answer (score 0):

Try this: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Xnzmd/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/Etbyg/1/

Hope it fits the cause `:)`

**Code**

```
var file = "Video/ogv/Task_2.4a_Host_treated.theora.ogv";

extension = file.match(/\.[^.]+$/);
filename = file.match(/(.*)\.[^.]+$/);
alert('extention =  '+extension);
alert('Filename = ' + filename[1])​
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question, so I'm not certain what you're trying to do. If you want to replace the filename, use this:

```
var newpath = filepath.replace(/[^/]*(?=\.\w+$)/, 'replacement');
```

If you want to extract the filename and get rid of everything else, try this:

```
var filename = filepath.replace(/.*\/|\.\w+$/g, '');
```

Comment: This will delete all slashes and the file extension, resulting in `VideowebmTask_2.4a_Host_treated`. Please test your solution.

Comment: @m.buettner - That's precisely what I'm trying to do. What makes you think that's the wrong behavior? Perhaps I was confused by the question.

Comment: The way I read the question, he wants to replace the file name (without the extension). I can't read anything about concatenating all directory names with the file name.

Comment: @m.buettner - I read it as trying to extract the filename, but now I'm not sure. See my edit for both choices.

Comment: Read my first comment again. Your second variant does not extract the file name, but removes slashes... so the directories in the path will be concatenated in front of the file name.

Comment: @m.buettner - I see now. You're correct; I make a mistake when I copied the pattern from my console. I've fixed it and tested it again.